# usb not detected on linux or windows but detected by BIOS

Tags: linux, windows-10, usb

So my USB Flash is not detected correctly on Windows 10 with following message in properties of device manager:
"Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)
A request for the USB device descriptor failed."
I tried all the solutions I could find so far for USB failing but non of them works. Also my deeping (GNU+Linux OS) does not detect it.
Problem is that when i plug it to my PC and start PC USB shows up in menu for selecting device to boot from and it's displayed correctly : ADATA...

Is there any way I could fix this USB. Once again It cannot be formated or detected as storage or fixed by removing devices in device manager or formated through default GNU tools which ship with deepin OS.

Answer (score 0):

Unplug it, run fdisk -l, note which drives are present, then plug the drive back in, run fdisk -l (sudo both times, of course) and see if it shows up.  Let us know.

Comment: Think I've done this and both times it shows up only HDD and SSD but I'll try again and report the output.

Comment: As it turns out nothing can help this USB. fdisk never shows flash drive.